# ClassCastException while using Hibernate Bean Validation

Tags: java, jboss, bean-validation, classcastexception

This is my first question here, so please bear with me :)

I am trying to implement a framework for assessing the data quality of a system by using bean validation. My system uses JBoss 7.1.1 and Hibernate 5.1.3. As a first step, I wanted to output some simple validation statistics, such as the percentage of violations per constraint type. To do that, I wanted to first get all the constraint annotations that I have declared in each entity (currently I only have class-level and field constraints). I thought I had found a way to do this by casting my ConstraintDescriptors to ConstraintDescriptorImpl and then calling the getAnnotationType() method on that (there's probably a more elegant way to do what I want, but this probably belongs to a different question). This all compiles fine, but at runtime I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.validator.metadata.ConstraintDescriptorImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.descriptor.ConstraintDescriptorImpl
```

What is going on here? The location of ConstraintDescriptorImpl in the hibernate-validator-5.1.3 JAR is org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.descriptor.ConstraintDescriptorImpl, which I am using in my import. After some googling, I found that org.hibernate.validator.metadata.ConstraintDescriptorImpl was the location of the class in hibernate-validator-4.x. In fact, I tried adding the hibernate-validator-4.1.0 JAR on my path, and the whole thing works smoothly. But this doesn't seem to answer my question (and I want to use the 5.1.3 version).

Since I don't use hibernate-validator-4.x anywhere else in the project, I suspect that maybe JBoss including hibernate-validator-4.2 in its modules could be to blame. But then again it might be a Hibernate validator issue. In any case, I have no idea how to solve or even debug the issue-any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assumption is correct, JBoss AS 7 does indeed bundle Hibernate Validator 4 in its modules directory. Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final to be precise and it's in *modules/org/hibernate/validator/main*. AS 7 uses Hibernate Validator to fulfill the Bean Validation requirements of the EE 6 spec (Hibernate Validator 4 is the reference implementation of Bean Valdiation 1.0).

If you want to bundle a different version of Validator with your AS 7 app, you'll need to use *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* to exclude the validation module. See also https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had tried to do what you suggest by following what is explained [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1933), but that had failed somehow (still got the same exception), so I was hoping it would be something else. Also, I was hoping to find a solution that wouldn't include having to touch JBoss and its modules (I'm supposed to leave it as is).
Do you know if there is a way to get my code choose the JAR in its library instead of the JBoss module through a properties or manifest file (i.e. without messing with the JBoss modules and files)?

Comment: jboss-deployment-structure.xml is the file which you should use if you don't want to mess with the modules directly. If you tried and it did not work, it is hard to tell what went wrong without additional information.